# How do you define a stored procedure with sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

How do you define a stored procedure with sequelize?

This doesn't work.

```
sequelize.query(
    `
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE do_something()
BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM some_table;

END

$$

DELIMITER ;
`);
```

Comment: What database do you use?  What error did you get?

Comment: If it is not really needed, you can make SP like function model, which is class method.
check this out, https://sequelizedocs.fullstackacademy.com/instance-and-class-methods/